KeyCloak custom SPI integration with Quarkus
How to setup and use features of quarkus in the integration with keycloak where we have custom SPI's, and implemented AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper,AbstractIdentityProviderMapper interfaces so that we can connect to keycloak server and test the flows of authentication etc
I have an existing project developed by team which is keyCloak application Now my task is to integrate the project with Quarkus just as application framework and use the functionalities like dependency injection etc.
As of now I am able to integrate with Quarkus and generate the jar file and add in the providers of keycloak server locally and using command kc.bat and login into  http://localhost:8080/admin/master/console
Now with Quarkus I would like to know if I need a main file with  Quarkus.run  and also how to debug locally by keeping breakpoints and what all dependencies are needed .I am referring this article :https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/main/quarkus
but not understanding  how to setup and debug locally and what all dependencies, application.properties if any are needed. I dont have any endpoints in quarkus.I am new to keycloak and Quarkus related stuff
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-example-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <keycloak.version>26.0.0</keycloak.version>
    <quarkus.version>2.13.3.Final</quarkus.version>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>2.13.3.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.native.builder-image>quay.io/quarkus/ubi-quarkus-native-image:21.3.0-java11</quarkus.native.builder-image>
    
  </properties>
   
   <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependencies>
        <!-- Quarkus dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Keycloak dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-server-spi-private</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
            <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
            <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Logging dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JUnit and Mockito for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>3.11.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code</goal>
                            <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>11</source>
          <target>11</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

